# wordpress post not showing my "<somehting>" text>?

Tags: posts, text, escaping

I am trying to make a post where there is a text line :

> some libraries to run which we will import by using "`#include <filename.h>`" command.

instead of outputting the text as it is. It shows as:

> some libraries to run which we will import by using “#include ” command.

in post so `<filename.h>` is missing for some reason. I am quite sure I am missing something here but unable to find. 
I think for some reason WordPress escapes anything between <> tags so how can i show them if i need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape th `<` and the `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, otherwise WordPress will remove the “unknown tags”.

You could also filter `pre_kses` to change the output before it gets stripped.

```
add_filter( 'pre_kses', function( $str ) {
    // find and escape < and > on specific positions, then
    return $str;
});
```

Comment: is there anything that I can add before < and > chars to escape them like in most programming languages like java or c we add "\" to escape them?

Comment: @shunya Yes, see my update.